# Changing date formats in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I change a date such as 06/26/1987 to June-1987 in Excel.   It needs to separate month into one column and year in a separate column.

So Column F on the spreadsheet reads 06/26/1997.   Column O = 6  Column P =1997

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In O2:

```
=MONTH(F2)
```

If you want the month in its name form then use this:

```
=TEXT(F2,"mmmm")
```

Or just:

```
=F2
```

And change the format to `mmmm`.

IN P2:

```
=YEAR(F2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question : Change MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in excel in date sequence

1. 6/12/2021 10:15:08 PM
2. 6/23/2021 6:04:35 PM
3. 7/1/2021 9:42:36 AM

Answer :
=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(N4,FIND(" ",N4)-1),"/","-"),"dd/mm/YYYY"),4),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(TEXT(LEFT(N4,FIND(" ",N4)-1),"dd/mm/YYYY"),1,2),"/","")),LEFT(RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(N4,FIND(" ",N4)-1),"/","-"),"dd/mm/YYYY"),10),7),2))